# How to place ListView inside of a Page?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, listview

I currently have some swipe pages and in all of them I want to have list with different data.
I am still pretty new to android so I tried all possible options I could come up with:

1. First I tried adding some xml layouts to the insides of the page.
2. Second I tried creating and populating lists pragmatically.

None of the above worked out for me.

For starters I want to check if I understand the concept:
*Swipe layout contains pages and data could be passed to them by `getItem()`  `Fragment` type content.*

And now how to achieve what I want:
*I have to add `LinearLayout` add a child `ListView` and finally add a child for that the `TextView` element to main page template in my `layout/main.xml` and create a data population method.*

**Is there something wrong in my reasoning and that is why I can't find answer or I just have not found the right source?**

CODE EXAMPLES:
`main.xml`

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <!--
    This title strip will display the currently visible page title, as well as the page
    titles for adjacent pages.
    -->

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="#33b5e5"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

`list_layout.xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

`MainActivity.java`

```
...    
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three primary sections
        // of the app.

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());


        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by declaring an xml say `listview.xml` in which define your `ListView`.
  You can either create a new `TextView` pro grammatically or create the new layout say `titleview.xml` in which write your title view using `TextView`.

Pro grammatically you can inflate both the views and pass your main layout parent view as parent to these child views.

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    ListView listview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view, parent);
    TextView textview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.textview, parent);
    layout.addView(textview);
    layout.addView(listview);
```

Comment: Where do I get parent and layout variables? I tried this:

RelativeLayout item = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.pager);
View list = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_view,null);
        item.addView(list); Did not work.

Comment: layout is your main view layout reference. Like if you have layout which shows the title on top of the screen and listview in the middle of the screen. Then a textview will be your first layout and then declare another parent layout can be LinearLayout or RelativeLayout. Get the reference of this layout in your activity. Now add the inflated view to your layout. linearlayout.add(listview); If you pass a parent view then android will apply all the properties of parent child. Otherwise you can pass null in place of parent.